# Delphi virtual treeview detect double click on cell

Tags: delphi

I know how to get the node that is focused when the treeview OnDblClick even fires. But is there any way to get the column index? I must be starring myself blind right now, but my Google searches have not been successful.

Comment: If you were looking for node double click event, then `OnNodeDblClick` event has `HitInfo` parameter which has `HitColumn` member. There you'd find this information.

Comment: Have you tried `FocusedColumn`?  Although, without testing I don't know if it is set before the `OnDblClick` event...

Comment: @TLama, shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: @Johan, not necessarily. With a pure `OnDblClick` you can track double clicking even outside nodes. Maybe OP wants to determine if a double click was performed over a certain node and/or column or over an empty space. From the question it's not clear. However, in the `OnDblClick` event you can still call the `GetHitTestInfoAt` method and get the same structure as I mentioned. But feel free to post an answer, I'm "busy" with a brand new virtual control, a virtual time line ;-)

Comment: @TLama If you make itt an answer, I will accept it. It solved my problem :)